How to Encrypt Streaming Data over UART using AES-256-CTR Mode in C with Cross-Platform Compatibility?
I'm working on a C program where I need to encrypt data that streams continuously over a UART port. Since the size of the data stream is unknown in advance, I'm using AES in CTR (Counter) mode, which suits streaming encryption. The setup includes:
Encryption Platform: Linux (ARM architecture).
Decryption Platform: Windows.
I'm using OpenSSL's EVP library for the AES encryption and base64 encoding to transfer the data as text.
Here's an outline of my current setup:
I have a thread monitoring event changes; when an event changes, a function is triggered to and data is streamed this data is written in CSV file I want to encrypt the data which is being streamed
I encrypt the data using AES-256 in CTR mode and then encode it with base64 for compatibility across different systems.
This is my code for encryption I'm using
void aes_encrypt(const unsigned char *input, 
                 unsigned char *output, 
                 int *output_length)
{

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create EVP_CIPHER_CTX\n");
        return; // Handle error
    }

    if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key_aes_2, iv_aes_2) != 1) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize encryption\n");
        return; // Handle error
    }

    int len;
    if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, output, &len, input, strlen((char *)input)) != 1) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        fprintf(stderr, "Encryption update failed\n");
        return; // Handle error
    }
    *output_length = len; // Set output length to the length of encrypted data

    printf("data encrypted\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
}

void base64_encode(const unsigned char *input, int input_length, unsigned char *output, int *output_length) {
    BIO *bio, *b64;
    BUF_MEM *buffer_ptr;

    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

    BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); // no newline
    BIO_write(bio, input, input_length);
    BIO_flush(bio);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(bio, &buffer_ptr);

    *output_length = buffer_ptr->length;
    BIO_read(bio, output, buffer_ptr->length);
    output[*output_length] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the output string

    printf("data encoded\n");

    BIO_free_all(bio);
}

Also while decryption process my half data is decrypted and half is some non printable binary values.
enter image description here
A solution for decryption process and is the encryption process right?

What does "half data" mean? Is first 128 bits of data decrypted correctly but the rest is not? Does unencrypted base64-encoded data transfer works correctly? Do you have any error detection on UART level? How do you syncronize streams on both encoder and decoder sides? How multithreading is related to this question?

I'm storing the data in csv on a linux system and then copying the csv into windows.I have data of 348 bytes which has header and some values, the headers and one line from the values are decrypted, rest of the data is non-printable binary values. You could look at the image I have attached

Does it work without encryption, i.e. base64 encoding only? If not, does it work for plain ascii strings even without base64? Find on which step your data is corrupted first. It is not known how your input/output buffers are allocated, how you call aes_encrypt() and base64_encode(), etc. The same for decryptor part.

void decrypt_file(const char *in, const char *out) {
FILE *f = fopen(in, "rb"); fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); long len = ftell(f); fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
unsigned char *b64 = malloc(len), *dec = malloc(len), *d = malloc(len + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);
fread(b64, 1, len, f); fclose(f);
int dl, dlen; base64_decode(b64, len, dec, &dl); aes_decrypt(dec, dl, d, &dlen);
f = fopen(out, "wb"); fwrite(d, 1, dlen, f); fclose(f);

free(b64); free(dec); free(d);

}

I'm decrypting the data by reading encrypted bytes stored in CSV. Also wanted to know if data is corrupted then also its wrote in CSV?

Do not put code in comments. Please [edit] your question to include the decryption code and other information you want to add.

I see calls to EVP_EncryptInit_ex and EVP_EncryptUpdate, but I see no call to EVP_EncryptFinal or EVP_EncryptFinal_ex. Does the encryption method that you chose work without the "Final" call? (I don't know the answer. I am only asking.)

As per i have search it works without EVP_EncryptFinal I'm also new in this so I'm also not sure.
